# Required Fields in a form triggered when removing child

Tags: javascript, html

I have a large form that allows the user to dynamically add more parts to the form. i have a container which i `appendChild` a new template to the form. This has a button which you can remove, however when i remove the template it goes up the top of page to the required fields. It does delete however this is not practical. How do i prevent this from happening?

```
var SectionToDelete= document.getElementById("SectionToDelete");    
var Container = document.getElementById("Container");
Container.removeChild(SectionToDelete);
```

Comment: sounds like duplicate ids.

Comment: @benG i went through and double checked and does seem to be. i add `formnovalidate` to the button and it does not outline the boxes red, however now scrolls to the top, do you reckon its because that div had focus?

Comment: @BenG it was a rookie error!!!! the type of the button was not set to `type="button"` Need to refill the coffee!